# How to know whether you can trust the output of R numerical integration?

Tags: r, integration

I am having trouble trusting R's ability to do numerical integration.  The following code:

```
integrand = function(xval) {dnorm(x=xval,mean=0,sd=1)}
integrate(integrand,-Inf,Inf)
```

correctly produces output of 1 with absolute error < 9.4e-05.

However, if I simply shift the distribution by a constant,

```
integrand2 = function(xval) {dnorm(x=xval,mean=370,sd=1)}
integrate(integrand2,-Inf,Inf)
```

it does not successfully integrate the probability distribution (i.e. integral should be one).  I get an answer of 4.360019e-15 with absolute error < 7.1e-15.

I understand that the numerical integration procedure has trouble finding the hump of the distribution, but how can I tell whether R's output is reliable or not?

Comment: Generally, you have to pass reasonable bounds to the integrate function, just as you would have to pass reasonable bounds to a local maximization function. How you choose those bounds depends on what you're using the integration for.

Comment: [similar question and some answers on r-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/253526.html)

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback.  I am breaking up the integrals from positive infinity to the mean of the distribution and then from the mean to positive infinity.  This seems to cure the issue, but it feels very ad-hoc.   `integrand3 = function(xval) {dnorm(x=xval,mean=370,sd=1)}`  
`a = integrate(integrand3,-Inf,370)`  
`b = integrate(integrand3,370,Inf)`  
`a$value + b$value`

Comment: AFAIK there's just no bullet-proof way to test the integrand over a finite number of points and yet be sure not to have missed a "region of interest". There could always be a bump somewhere in (-Inf, Inf) that escapes the quadrature points, if you're unlucky and/or didn't know anything about the integrand _a priori_. Plotting it over some sensible range is always good. Sometimes once you know where the important bits are, you can do a simple change of variable to make sure the quadrature samples that region more optimally (e.g. here, shift and perhaps scale the axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question, Adam. I didn't know the issue before I read this page.
I'll make a suggestion to this issue, though it is not a perfect answer.
The integrate function actually returns a list, and the 3rd item, $subdivisions, can be used to measure reliability.

```
> integrate(integrand,-Inf,Inf)$subdivisions
[1] 3
> integrate(integrand2,-Inf,Inf)$subdivisions
[1] 1
```

I said "not perfect", because the value 3 is also small. So, this method overestimates the unreliability. Maybe, it can be used to show some warnings. Details are available on [my blog](http://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/reliability-of-integrate/).